# How to use variable in CURL command?

Tags: shell, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I am using below line in my pipeline in shared library. It doesn't work. Can anyone please help me with a fix?

`ApplicationName` is a input parameter to function.

```
sh 'curl -u $USERPASS "$UDEPLOY_URL/cli/application/environmentsInApplication?application=${ApplicationName}" > uDeployEnvChoice.json'
```

Comment: I have tried below options and it dosent work -> (1) application=${ApplicationName} 
(2) application=$ApplicationName
(3) application=${ApplicationName}
(4) application="'"$ApplicationName"'"
(5) application=\"$ApplicationName\"

Answer (score 0):

Groovy does string interpolation only for text between double quotes.

I suggest you to do an "echo" instead of "curl" first to see your command.

And prefere ' -o uDeployEnvChoice.json' option to redirect curl response body to your file. Thus, you should see curl output and could add -v flag to have more information.

Answer (score 0):

I used withEnv in my function under shared library. It worked. when using sh or bat, we need to use withEnv

def getEnvironmentChoice(String ApplicationName){
def CHOICES = []

```
        withEnv(["ApplicationName=${ApplicationName}"]){     
             withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'SCM_Credential_ID', variable: 'USERPASS')])
              {
              echo "In Shared Lib: ${applicationName}"
              sh 'curl -u $USERPASS "$UDEPLOY_URL/cli/application/environmentsInApplication?application=$ApplicationName" > uDeployEnvChoice.json'
              }
            }                  
            def uDeployJsonData
            uDeployJsonData = readJSON file:'uDeployEnvChoice.json'
               
            echo "Size: ${uDeployJsonData.size()}"
               
            for(i = 0; i < uDeployJsonData.size(); i++)
            {  
             CHOICES.add(uDeployJsonData[i].name)
            }
               
            return CHOICES
```

}